# Changing A0 poster template to A1 format

Tags: templates, posters

I'm using this LaTeX template [Link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/latex-portrait-poster-template/gybjbztdkvyg#.VUywIs5GylI) from latextemplates.com, but I can't get the format set to A1 size without ruining the layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not knowing what 'ruining the layout' means, I can offer the following. If you make an A0-sized PDF of the poster and print to fit on A1 paper, everything will scale down accordingly, with no changes in layout. If you want the font sizes of A0 on A1, you'll need to look through the template and adjust any fixed length (for example, `\columnsep=100pt`) to fit the new page size.

Comment: @MikeRenfro What about the font size? I would like 25 pt but I can't find where I can change it?

Comment: According to [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/a0poster/a0_eng.pdf), `\normalsize` is already approximately 25 point by default. And the linked template uses various font size commands to increase or decrease the font size as required. You're going to need to provide a more specific question that shows the problem you're running into.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Yes, it would be 25 pt when printed on A0 paper, but it will look a lot smaller printed on A1, so to be more specific, I want to alter the \normalsize line to fit the font to a smaller size.

Comment: Are you saying that if you use a0poster document class with the a1 option as you'd stated earlier, that `\normalsize` isn't 25 points by default? Try it with your linked template, and with an ordinary a0poster with minimal content. And if you post a MWE to illustrate the problem, it would be much easier to demonstrate the issue.